# non-constexpr object usable in static_assert

Tags: c++

I'll lead with the example

```
#include <array>

// Just in case std::array has superpowers...
template <typename T, unsigned n>
struct dummy {
    constexpr unsigned size() const noexcept {
        return n;
    }

    unsigned badsize() const noexcept {
        return n;
    }
};

void fun()
{
    std::array<int, 8> arr{};
    static_assert(arr.size() == 8); // OK

    dummy<int, 8> arr2{};
    static_assert(arr2.size() == 8); // OK
    static_assert(arr2.badsize() == 8); // Compiler Error
}
```

The question is:

What is the language mechanism/rules that has allowed the **non-const(expr)** variables `arr` and `arr2` to have their **non-static but constexpr** member functions `size()` be evaluated as a constant expression (bool-constexpr in particular)?

I've spent some time now searching SO and cppreference.com, but cannot work out why this is allowed.

I've recently had to update similar code to do `static_assert(std::tuple_size_v<decltype(arr)> == 8)` when upgrading from an older version of GCC, so I thought it was perhaps just some GCC extension at first. But I've now had this kind of code start working again with neweer versions of GCC, and I want to understand what's going on here.

Comment: interesting. If `size` accesses a data member then `arr` must be `constexpr`. https://godbolt.org/z/jvv9PTbf4

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr Here they mentioned "Core Constant Expression" in the constraint of constexpr function. (See next comment)

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression Here they defined "Core Constant Expression", see the very first term in the list, it has a special treatment on this pointer though I can't understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There really isn’t any *good* reason this is allowed: it’s just that passing the address of the (non-constexpr) local variables as `this` to a member function is **not considered** in the rules for constant expressions.  It’s even permitted to use `this` in the function called, but you can’t use any of the (non-static) **member variables** of the class unless they really were initialized as constants.  Of course, these size functions don’t need to do so even if they aren’t actually **static**.

What’s really confusing is that this permission doesn’t extend to **references**: using them is considered a read of the effective pointer value, and that must separately be a constant.  There are active proposals to allow such usage under the same inevitable restrictions on using the member variables of such an “unknown object”.

Comment: This also applies to (pointer and reference) function parameters. If you don't use them, they don't need to be constexpr: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/rEx1cK7zf